# Is it possible to prove that $p\to q$ from these axioms and theorems?

Tags: propositional-calculus

My professor insists this is possible, I say it isn't.  What say you?

> Certain theorems and axioms have been established or assumed.
>
> *Axiom 1:* $p\rightarrow {\sim y}$
>   *Axiom 2:* ${\sim q}\rightarrow r$
>   *Theorem 1:* $p\rightarrow {\sim z}$
>   *Theorem 2:* $x\rightarrow \text{either }q\text{ or }z$
>   *Theorem 3:* $r\rightarrow \text{either }x\text{ or }y$
>
> Prove, in outline form, that $p\rightarrow q$.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that it's not possible?

Comment: @littleO Sorry, meant that question for OP.

Comment: It is possible. ${}{}$

Comment: The question isn't whether it's possible.  The question is whether it's necessary.

Comment: @Paul the title as well as OP says "possible". I think "possible" is what OP intends.

Comment: @Paul actually op asked only what we would say. I could also write foobar.

Comment: I guess the law of excluded middle is needed here. eg take p=~~a, q=a, y=r=~a, x=z=F. Then all the given hypotheses hold, and we must prove ~~a->a.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Assume that $p\to q$ is false that is $p\wedge \neg q$ is true.

1. (hyp) $p\wedge \neg q$.
2. (1. and Axiom 1) $p\wedge (p\to \neg y)\implies \neg y$
3. (1. and Axiom 2) $\neg q\wedge (\neg q\to r)\implies r$
4. (2., 3. and Theorem 3)    $r\wedge \neg y\wedge (r\to x \oplus y)\implies x$
5. (1., 4. and Theorem 2)    $x\wedge \neg q \wedge (x\to q \oplus z)\implies z$
6. (5. and Theorem 1)    $z\wedge  (z\to \neg p)\implies \neg p$
7. (1. and 6.) $p\wedge \neg p$ (contradiction)

Hence $p\to q$ is proved.

P.S. $\wedge$  is the AND operator, $\neg$ is the NOT operator and $\oplus$ is the EXCLUSIVE OR operator.

Comment: @Dana Hill $\wedge$  is the AND operator So $p\wedge \neg q$ is true  means that $p$ is true and $q$ is false (i.e. $p\to q$ does not hold).

Comment: "it could be that "not p and q" is true"" . That's right. Check with the truth table of the implication: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Implies.html

Comment: @Dana Hill The process from 1 to 7 show that if  $p\wedge \neg q$ is true then we have a contradiction. Hence $p\wedge \neg q$ is false. This means that $(p,q)$ could be $(F,T)$, $(F,F)$  or $(T,T)$. Those three couples are precisely the true values of $p\to q$. Is it clear now?

Comment: This proof continues to work even when $\oplus$ is replaced by $\vee$.

Answer (score 3):

Direct proof (that is, not by contradiction)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{ (1.1) }& \textrm{  for Theorem 2: }& \sim z \rightarrow \sim x \textrm{ or } (x \textrm{ and } q)\\ 
\textrm{ (1.2) }& \textrm{  for Theorem 1 and (1.1): }& p \rightarrow \sim x \textrm{ or } (x \textrm{ and } q)\\ 
\textrm{ (2.1) }& \textrm{ for (1.2) and Axiom 1: }&  p \rightarrow (\sim x \textrm{ and } \sim y) \textrm{ or } (x \textrm{ and } q  \textrm{ and } \sim y) \\
\textrm{ (3.1) }& \textrm{ for Theorem 3: }&  \sim x \textrm{ and } \sim y \rightarrow  \sim r\\
\textrm{ (3.2) }& \textrm{ }&  x \textrm{ and } q  \textrm{ and } \sim y \rightarrow  q\\
\textrm{ (3.3) }& \textrm{ for (2.1), (3.1), and (3.2): }& p \rightarrow \sim r \textrm{ or }q \\
\textrm{ (4.1) }& \textrm{ for Axiom 2: }& \sim r \rightarrow q \\
\textrm{ (4.2) }& \textrm{ for (3.3) and (4.1): }& p \rightarrow q \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Little bit short. How have you eliminated $\sim x$?

Comment: How do you obtain your second statement?

Comment: The middle statement looks to be incorrect.

Comment: @user251257 my fault, thanks +1. Robert Z answered correctly

Comment: @John Bentin my fault, thanks +1. Robert Z answered correctly

Comment: @Paul my fault, thanks +1. Robert Z answered correctly

Comment: This is what's in the book's solution manual.  Sloppy and wrong.

Comment: @Dana Hill sorry for having post a wrong proof. I edited my answer with a direct proof. Hope it will be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

1. the axioms are using the arrow and tilde to mean implication and negation respectively and that
2. the axioms establish four primitive constants $p,\,y,\,q,\,r$ and that
3. the theorems treat $x$ and $z$ as variables which can take on the values of any of the four primitive constants

then by Theorem 1

1. $p \rightarrow\neg p$
2. $p \rightarrow\neg\neg p\rightarrow p$
3. $p \rightarrow\neg y$
4. $p \rightarrow\neg\neg y\rightarrow y$
5. $p \rightarrow\neg r$
6. $p \rightarrow\neg\neg r\rightarrow r$
7. $p \rightarrow\neg q$
8. $p \rightarrow\neg\neg q\rightarrow q$

Of course, only this last implication is needed.

Comment: I don't know that your (3) is right.  I'm taking r,p,q,x,y,z to all be separate things.  Why would you assume any of them could replace another?

Comment: That's my point. There is too much missing context. My list of assumptions was just one possible way to fill in unstated context.